# Is it possible to use props in React.hooks?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component X it accepts Y from props. Is it possible to use Y in hooks?[cod](https://codesandbox.io/s/5k23oprn6n)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function X({ y }) {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(y);
  const ADD = () => {
    setIndex(index + 1);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {index}
      <button onClick={ADD}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just now saw the link to your code. What is your question exactly? Your code works fine.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that’s the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a prop as argument to `useState` works great for setting an initial value.

**Example**

```js
const { useState } = React;

function X({ y }) {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(y);
  const add = () => {
    setIndex(index + 1);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {index}
      <button onClick={add}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<X y={5} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: As I know, in a class, giving state an initial value is the action of the anti-pattern.[example](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key) ,and if the hooks have no such problem, then where did you get such information?

Comment: @EdgarYedigaryan It's en anti-pattern if you have to keep state up to date both in a parent component and in the child component, but using a prop for default value if that's not the case is not an anti-pattern, neither in a class or function component.

Comment: as I understand it, if in my example the props will change then my code will be anti-pattern?

Comment: @EdgarYedigaryan Yes, if your `y` prop will change, and you want the `X` component to react to that change, it's probably a better option to store the state directly in the parent and update that value there instead and just use `y` directly in `X` so it automatically stays up to date with the prop.